# Limiting the rows where sum of two columns subtraction equals a value

Tags: php, mysql

I'm processing some files in PHP and using MySQL to store results. Here is how my table looks like:

`tblConverts`:

```
  ID   ACCESS_KEY    STATUS     TOTAL_PAGES   PROCESSED_PAGES  
 ---- ------------ ----------- ------------- ----------------- 
   1   upYP5RbNqQ   COMPLETED            10                10  
   2   IeH02qBAtV   WAITING              32                18  
   3   Di5sCWxA2p   REJECTED             28                 0  
   4   Aft54Xhr3f   WAITING              40                 0  
   5   TzU1VMoeQF   WAITING              30                 0
```

I want to make my batch script to work on "WAITING" marked records until it reaches to a point where sum of two columns (TOTAL_PAGES - PROCESSED_PAGES) equals to 100 for example.

The way I implement this is to query:

`SELECT * FROM tblConverts WHERE status = 'WAITING' AND TOTAL_PAGES > PROCESSED_PAGES LIMIT 500`

And then in PHP script I make a loop and subtract rows until a counter reaches 100. But using this method by combining SQL and PHP is not a good idea. How can I implement this function as only a single SQL query?

**UPDATE**:

Imagine 20 pages per execution (entire rows, no each row), first and third rows are not matching condition so we'll work on second, fourth and fifth rows. From second row we have 14 pages (32 - 18). Because row #2's remaining pages is less than 20, it should look for next. Next one (#4) has 40 pages so the sum of remaining pages (14 + 40) is bigger than 20. So it must stop here and return the rows (#2 and #4).

Comment: Well, you wrote that first query with `TOTAL_PAGES > PROCESSED_PAGES`. And you know what you want: `TOTAL PAGES - PROCESSED_PAGES = 100` (though in reality `>=` or `<=` is probably a better choice). How do you _think_ your query should be changed?

Comment: @Chris I have updated my question, please let me know if I couldn't explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this and let me know if you are looking for the same.

Note: 20 is limit as you mention in your question. You can change it as per your requirement.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    tblConverts
WHERE
    ID IN (
        SELECT
            m1.ID
        FROM
            tblConverts m1
        LEFT JOIN tblConverts m2 ON m1.ID >= m2.ID
        WHERE
            m1. STATUS = 'WAITING'
        AND m2. STATUS = 'WAITING'
        GROUP BY
            m1.ID
        HAVING
            SUM(
                m2.TOTAL_PAGES - m2.PROCESSED_PAGES
            ) - SUM(m1.TOTAL_PAGES) / COUNT(m1.TOTAL_PAGES) < 20
    )
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much, this is what I want. Just a question, I don't understand complex SQL queries, why you have checked both m1.status and m2.status? and what does m1.id means here? are we pointing m1 to the first SELECT's result?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Basic login for this query is left join with `>=` on column `id`, so that i have to set 'status' condition 'waiting' for both the aliases. I have created two aliases for same table (like we do in self join) so m1.id is column of alias m1 table. i have implemented group by on m1 table so that there must be m1.id in select statement.